# Using WP_Query, I want to show posts that are associated with a custom taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called event. Custom taxonomy called event categories, which has various terms.  I want to show all the events that belong to a certain custom taxonomy term on a archive page.

I am including the custom taxonomy term wrongly, as it displays all the events and not just ones that are classified in a term of the custom taxonomy. It displays only events that are in the future, which I want.

```
<?php
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); $termst = $term->slug; 
 $current_date = date('Y-m-d'); //Get the current date in the same format as date fields normally store in db
          $args = array(  
                  'post_type' => 'event',
                  'posts_per_page' => 4, // Number of event posts you want to query                                
                  'meta_key' => '_event_start_date',
                  'orderby' => '_event_start_date',
                  'order'  => 'ASC', // Order posts starting with the closest date to current date
                  'tax_query' => array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'event-categories',
      'field'    => 'slug', 
                  'term' => $termst
                  ),

                  'meta_query' => array(
                      array(
                          'key' => '_event_start_date',
                          'value' => $current_date,
                          'compare' => '>=', //Compare $current_date with _event_start_date and show only the post with a date after or equal $current_date
                                    'type' => 'DATE',
                                ),
                            )
                        ); 
               $query = new WP_Query( $args );
   if($query ->have_posts()) : 
      while($query ->have_posts()) : 
         $query ->the_post();
 ?>
         <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
      <?php   echo ' - '. get_post_meta($id, '_event_start_date', true)    ?>
      <?php
      endwhile;
   else: 
?>      Oops, there are no posts.
<?php    endif;?>
```

How can I include the current taxonomy term here, so that it only shows events that have been assigned to a specific term? Thank-you!

**UPDATED:** I have changed my code to the recommendation, but now it says `Oops, there are no posts.` . Can anyone take a look and tell me what is wrong please? There are posts.

```
<?php
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); $termst = $term->slug; 
 $current_date = date('Y-m-d'); //Get the current date in the same format as date fields normally store in db
          $args = array(  
                  'post_type' => 'event',
                  'posts_per_page' => 4, // Number of event posts you want to query                                
                  'meta_key' => '_event_start_date',
                  'orderby' => '_event_start_date',
                  'order'  => 'ASC', // Order posts starting with the closest date to current date
                  'tax_query' => array(
  // second array
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'event-categories',
      'field'    => 'slug', 
      'term' => $termst
    )
     // end second array
  ),
                  'meta_query' => array(
                      array(
                          'key' => '_event_start_date',
                          'value' => $current_date,
                          'compare' => '>=', //Compare $current_date with _event_start_date and show only the post with a date after or equal $current_date
                                    'type' => 'DATE',
                                ),
                            )
                        ); 

               $query = new WP_Query( $args );
   if($query ->have_posts()) : 
      while($query ->have_posts()) : 
         $query ->the_post();
 ?>
         <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
      <?php   echo ' - '. get_post_meta($id, '_event_start_date', true)    ?>
      <?php
      endwhile;
   else: 
?>      Oops, there are no posts.
<?php    endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tax query should be an array of arrays.

> Important Note: tax_query takes an array of tax query arguments arrays
>   (it takes an array of arrays). This construct allows you to query
>   multiple taxonomies by using the relation parameter in the first
>   (outer) array to describe the boolean relationship between the
>   taxonomy arrays.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

```
'tax_query' => array(
  // second array
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'event-categories',
      'field'    => 'slug', 
      'terms' => $termst
    )
  // end second array
  ),
```

Second, the "key" is `terms` not `term` as you have it.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the code you provided, but now I get 'Oops, there are no posts.'  when there are posts. I have added the code under updated,I would really appreciate it if you could have a look for me please.

Comment: @mattnewbie : See the edit